# Unable to swtich to nvidia graphic card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

I recently installed Nvidia graphics card on my laptop. However even after installation the machine is still using the Intel graphic chip. I tried running `prime-select nvidia`, the output being `nvidia profile is already set` but whenever I try checking which graphic card I am using, by,

```
lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA
```

the output is still

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 [8086:1916] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

I also tried

```
optirun glxinfo|egrep "OpenGL vendor|OpenGL renderer"
```

output

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 5.0, 256 bits)
```

but still no effect. I tried going to the `nvidia-setting` to configure the prime profile through the GUI, but the `prime profile` tab is not displayed. 
NOTE: I installed nvidia-prime through a deb file, `apt install nvidia-prime` didn't seem to work.

**UPDATE**
The output from `sudo lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3&&sudo lshw -c display`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 [8086:1916] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Skylake GT2 [HD Graphics 520] [103c:820c]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 520
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:131 memory:a2000000-a2ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM108M [GeForce 940MX]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:134 memory:a3000000-a3ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128)
```

Comment: Will you add the output of `sudo lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3&&sudo lshw -c display` to your question?

Comment: done @L.D.James

Comment: What release of Ubuntu & which nvidia driver version/

Comment: Are you still having problems switching to nvidia?  If the command provided in the answer doesn't work, you may have some other unexpected issue, which I'm sure I would be able to help with.  If it works, it may be a contribution back to the community for others trying to switch to preferred drives, to find solutions that work.

Comment: I recently had the chance to try your solution out. Thank You so much. It worked for me flawlessly and even on my buddies system, who switched to Linux only, recently. @L.D.James

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can switch nvidia graphics drivers from the commandline using this command:**

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-###
```

(Replace the ### with the number of the version you want to switch to.)

Currently the latest version from the repository is `nvidia-384`.  The latest version # from the [Official nVidia Website](http://www.nvidia.com) will depend on which specific card you specify in the download option.

You have nvidia **[GeForce 940MX]** which is compatible with nvidia-384 driver (currently the highest nvidia in the repository).  You can install it with this command:

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-384
```

The following command will show you the current drivers you have installed on your computer:

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
```

This command will show you all the available drivers in the repository, **and will include any PPA's** you have installed:

```
$ apt search nvidia - | egrep "^nvidia-[0-9]+\/"
```

Because it appears that you have downloaded drivers from nvida, you will see a later version than the one in the default repository.  You can use the command to install that driver by replacing `install nvidia-384` with the number you see from the previous command `install nvidia-xxx`.

**Note:**

If you inadvertently select an unstabled version that causes the desktop not to properly load, you can change the driver to the `nvidia-384` (or working version) from the console (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>).

After the install of a different driver, this command shows which one is currently in use:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3
```

In your case, results from the requested command shows that you currently have the **[HD Graphics 520]** driver being used.

---

You can use this direct link to [nVidia's Driver Downloads](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx?lang=en-us).  From the `Operating System` drop-down, choose your version of Ubuntu.

Currently the highest nVidia driver version that I find is in the PPA provided by [Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in.html), which is version **nvidia-396**.