# how can I check my GPU is installed correctly?

Tags: drivers, nvidia

I asked [how I can install my nvidia card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1026179/how-to-install-a-gtx-1060) and got forwarded to [How do I install the Nvidia drivers?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/how-do-i-install-the-nvidia-drivers).

So I did the basic commands (ppa, update...) , but nothing seemed to happen. I read the tutorial couple of times, for being a very basic user I dont understand it and I m afraid of making it worse.

`$ apt search nvidia - | egrep "^nvidia-[0-9]+\/"`

gave out

`WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.`

`nvidia-304/xenial 304.137-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1 amd64
nvidia-331/xenial 340.106-0ubuntu0+gpu16.04.2 amd64
nvidia-340/xenial 340.106-0ubuntu0+gpu16.04.2 amd64
nvidia-346/xenial 352.63-0ubuntu3 amd64
nvidia-352/xenial 361.42-0ubuntu2 amd64
nvidia-361/xenial-updates,xenial-security 367.57-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64
nvidia-367/xenial-updates,xenial-security 375.66-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64
nvidia-375/xenial 384.130-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1 amd64
nvidia-384/xenial 384.130-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.1 amd64
nvidia-387/xenial 390.48-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.3 amd64
nvidia-390/xenial,now 390.48-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.3 amd64  [installed]
nvidia-396/xenial 396.18-0ubuntu0~gpu16.04.2 amd64`

and

`$ ubuntu-drivers devices` gave out literally nothing.

`$ sudo lspci | grep -i vga` gave out:

`00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)`

(which might be my onboard graphic... (?))

`$ sudo lshw -C display` gave out:

```
*-display               
   Beschreibung: VGA compatible controller
   Produkt: 4th Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
   Hersteller: Intel Corporation
   Physische ID: 2
   Bus-Informationen: pci@0000:00:02.0
   Version: 06
   Breite: 64 bits
   Takt: 33MHz
   Fähigkeiten: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   Konfiguration: driver=i915 latency=0
   Ressourcen: irq:28 memory:f7800000-f7bfffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:f000(Größe=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: It is not seeing your NVIDIA card.  Try reinserting your card and possibly checking your BIOS if there is something about the card not being enabled.  If `lspci` cannot see it, then installing the drivers do not make any difference.  Also, make sure that your monitor is plugged into the new video card.

Comment: this is possible, my monitor is still plugged to my motherboard... cuz GPU is not runnin?

Comment: Yes, that is a very big possibility.  Plug it into the video card itself.  Some systems can detect where the monitor is plugged in and activate that video card.

Comment: Turn off the system first, move the cable over then boot it up.

Comment: Card didnt get activated when I plugged it...

Comment: Your system is not seeing the card.  Is the extra power rails plugged into the card?

Comment: Um, extra power rails?I didnt see a slot for that?

Comment: https://images10.newegg.com/ProductImageCompressAll1280/14-127-963-06.jpg  On that pic, upper right, there is an 8 pin power connector that needs to be connected.

Comment: @terrance it works now, got my connector, plugged my screen and I'm able to open Nvidia X Server Settings. Thank you :)

Comment: You're very welcome!  Glad I didn't give up on helping you!  Enjoy your new video card!  :)

Answer (score 2):

There is, indeed, a "control panel" in Ubuntu.  It's called **System Settings**.  You can launch most applications by typing part of the name or description in the Unity Launch Button.  It's on the top of the Sidebar Launcher.

Once you have brought up **System Settings**, click on **Software & Updates**.  Then click on the **Additional Drivers** Tab.

The app will analyze your configuration and give you the results you are asking for.  This will include a list of your installed drivers.  It's also flag a recommended driver based on the drives you have installed.  And, of course, as you have asked, it will show you the driver that you are currently using.  Usually, if there is a detected problem with the driver, you'll see a message to that effect.

You can also use this GUI app for changing and testing some of the other drivers you have installed.

The links in your question show you resources for locating and installing Nvidia drivers.  The installation for installing the drivers are usually in the form of a PPA provided by the vendor.  At times it will be a file that is run from the commandline.  They also provide *.deb files, which can be installed by clicking on them.

If you install a driver that is causing problems getting your GUI screen, you can use the commandlines (which is also included in the links you posted) from a terminal console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to fix it by running the command line version of the drivers install utility.

The commanline version is:

**Check for available drivers**

```
$ ubuntu-drivers devices
```

**Install a different driver**

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-###
```

(The ### is replaced by the version of the available drivers you have on your machine.)

**Show which driver is currently in use**

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3
```

Driver install commands are included in the Links you posted in your question, plus [this link - Switching NVidia Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/a/1023996/29012).

Comment: the additional drivers tab shows me no drivers were found (I installed `$ sudo apt-get install nvidia-390`). You mean the .deb file from [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads?target_os=Linux&target_arch=x86_64&target_distro=Ubuntu&target_version=1604)? So I just purge the nvidia-390 I just installed, and run the .deb by mouseclick? :)

Comment: @PortWein If the Additional Drivers comes up blank you are missing the part of adding the correct PPA.  In that answer that you were forwarded to, all the commands that they are having you type in you need to be doing from a Terminal Window.  Best is to copy and paste.  Without the PPA setup, you shouldn't have been able to run `sudo apt install nvidia-390` as it should have given you an error about not found.

Comment: Will you edit your question and paste the output of this command (from the answer) `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices`?  Did you get an error message when you run the `sudo apt install nvidia-390` command?  @Terrance Maybe right that you never completed the `PPA` configuration, which must include the command `sudo apt update` after you have added the PPA.  The **deb** file method should suffice to add the available drivers to your system.

Comment: @terrance: I did `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` and `sudo apt-get update` before I installed nvidia-390...

Comment: @L.D.James: `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` gives out nothing. Shall I just reinstall nividia-390 without any further actions? It's weird...

Comment: Are you sure you showed the full output of `apt search nvidia - | egrep "^nvidia-[0-9]+\/"` in your question?  You may be missing some default repository links.

Comment: @PortWein I just ran that `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa` on a system without a NVIDIA card in it and it too shows me no drivers.  Are you certain that you have a NVIDIA card in your system?  Please edit your question and put in the output of `sudo lspci | grep -i vga`

Comment: @L.D.James: Edited my full output...

Comment: @terrance: yes I guess as the lights are on...

Comment: @PortWein Currently you are using Intel Graphics. You may not have an NVidia card.  Please run this command and add the output to your question.  `sudo lshw -C display`