# Graphic card not recognized by Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, grub2, amd-graphics

A while ago I bought a Dell computer (Vostro 15 3568) that came with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS OS.
The computer has(/had) an AMD R5 M420 graphic card installed on it.
For about 2 years my system recognized my graphic card (when I looked on the detatils of the OS on ubuntu), I had no problems even when I upgraded to 18.04 LTS.

A month ago my whole OS crashed and wouldn't load any more, prompting an error on boot that the graphic card faild (can't remember the exact error message).

After a day trying to fix it I decided to reset my computer to factory settings and rebuild everything I have lost. Since then, my computer refuse to recognize my graphic card.
Currently I work on 18.04 LTS and the details window shows the following info:

[image: My system details]

trying `lspci` command gives the following output:

```
    lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
```

It might be useful to mention that while trying to fix my computer I have watched some videos recommanding to disable my graphic card through grub. I did so, but after seeing it doesn't work I changed it back.

[image: My current grub file]

What I changed back then was adding `nomodeset` to the end of the line arrowed (inside the quoteation marks). Of course `update-grub` was executed after every change.

Any idea why the OS doesn't recognize my graphic card, and how can I make it use it?

Comment: Said error was graphics card fail.  Did you repair/replaced or test card to see if it work?  Resetting of computer usually just means turning OS back to original default.  Just checking so I understand.

Comment: Yup seems like a hardware issue to me rather than software issue. It would help if you could be a more specific regarding the error message. In general if you were not messing with system files or trying something adventurous or you have not done any kernel updates and you get some message like that, usually is hardware related. But without any more details it is really hard to pin point at anything.

Comment: hmmm... i cant remember the exact failure message.
can you direct me somehow to check?
Could be hardware, though the failure occured after trying to install Ardour. my OS crashed and refused to load anymore.

Comment: Can see this link, read it over a few times, BUT DO NOT INSTALL anything.  This is for nivida not amd.  It might give you a few things to check.   https://askubuntu.com/questions/1027595/how-can-i-check-my-gpu-is-installed-correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thank you all for your aid, however none of those solved my problem.
The issue was that i couldnt find a proper driver for my Graphic Card supporting linux.

However when some focal fossa (20.04 LTS) reviews started to get published one of the first things I heard is that it features more support in Graphic Cards in both Nvidia and AMD. And indeed once I upgraded my distro the system started recognizing my radeon once again.

So not exactly a proper fix for the problem, but it works.

p.s.
If after the upgrade I had no success, I thought about calling the company that sold me the company or even straight to dell, and ask for an adequate driver. It's a long shot, but I figured if the OS recognized it once that means someone made the introduction between them at some point, so the driver is somewhere out there...