# Xorg process - what is it, how to disable it

Tags: xorg, cpu, fan

**Big problem:** my computer used a lot of cooler work, so I checked the processes by: terminal -> Top .. and the process Xorg uses about 40% of my CPU. Enough!
**Discovered:** xorg is a display server (whatever it means)

I can not shut it down by killall PROCESSNAME/killall PROCESSID, probably there is a reason for that.

**Question:**
Is it necessary to have it?
If no -> how can I disable it?
If yes -> how can I make it use less of my CPU?

Comment: If this is an Ubuntu Desktop system, killing Xorg will promptly crash your system and lose all unsaved data. It's the un-sexy foundation of your graphical system. Make it use less of your CPU by doing fewer simultaneous graphics-intensive tasks: Window swooshes and animations, watching movies in browser windows, remote desktop access, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `Xorg` binary runs the X desktop. You don't say which version of Ubuntu you're using. You should specify these things in your questions to get better answers. Please edit the question to clarify.

Anyway, if this is not a desktop system and you aren't using any form of graphical desktop environment on it then you could remove the relevant package, which is:

```
$ dpkg -S Xorg
xserver-xorg-core: /usr/bin/Xorg
xserver-xorg-legacy: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg.wrap
xserver-xorg-core: /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
xserver-xorg-legacy: /usr/share/man/man1/Xorg.wrap.1.gz
xserver-xorg-core: /usr/share/man/man1/Xorg.1.gz
```

Due to dependencies, removing any of those will want to remove a great deal of other packages too.

However, the fact that it's running and using 40% CPU suggests you actually are using it. If you are using any kind of graphical desktop environment here then it won't be a good idea to try to remove the package for this binary.

If you do need it then it's difficult to work out why it's using so much CPU unfortunately.

If it's always done this, you may need to install drivers for any graphics hardware you have. [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1027599/19809) covers installing additional graphics drivers.

If it's a new symptom, well, it could just be a one-off problem that may be resolved by rebooting. Normally you would only expect high CPU usage on the Xorg process when there is heavy use of video or similar in some window.